# How to copy & paste file in phone Gap using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova

I am using phoneGap framework to create mobile application . and i am putting my existing .db file in www directory of phoneGap . And when application loads or on some action i want to copy .db file from www directory to internal memory of application i.e /data/data/applicationPackageName/app_databases so that database could be loaded from this location. and all this i want to do using javascript/jquery/PhoneGap api .

plz help me with some code or article link. thanks a lot .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use FileRead and FileWrite from the the PhoneGap API to do this.

You can read more about the file actions on phonegap's documentation pages:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: Actually, you can't do this with the FileWriter as it cannot write binary data. You'll need to do this in native code. I should write a plugin for this someday but my todo list is pretty long right now. Check out http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence)

Comment: @SimonMacDonald i checked out this link at ur blog http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/12/on-fourth-day-of-phonegapping-creating.html as an alternative . And even i will try this link given by u.

Answer (score 0):

**Use FileEntry** from PhoneGap API for

copyTo:Copy a file to a different location on the file system
 or 
moveTo:Move a file to a different location on the file system.

And also you have to look at
    **window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, copySuccess, fail);**

See the refference
[enter link description here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileEntry)